# user account system PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication

Hi everybody this is my first question so please dont kill me if i explain myself wrongly.
I'm trying to make a user account system with a database, the problem is that when someone logs in if another user logs in and changes the URL from his account id: index.php?us=7 
to index.php?us=270 he/she can enter the other users vip page.
this is the login control code.

```
<?

//incluir librerias
include_once "funciones/funciones_BD.php";
include_once "constantes/constantes.php";

//abrir BD
Abrir_BD($link,$Servidor,$Usuario,$Clave,$BD);

$id = mysql_query("SELECT xidusuario FROM tblreferidos_usuarios WHERE xemail='".htmlentities($_REQUEST["email"])."'",$link);
$xid = mysql_fetch_row($id);
$usuario = mysql_query("SELECT xemail FROM tblreferidos_usuarios WHERE xemail='".htmlentities($_REQUEST["email"])."'",$link);
$Nusuario = mysql_num_rows($usuario);

//Si existe el usuario, validamos también la contraseña ingresada y el estado del usuario…
if($Nusuario != 0){
$clave = mysql_query("SELECT xpass FROM tblreferidos_usuarios WHERE xestado=1 AND xemail='".htmlentities($_REQUEST["email"])."' AND xpass='".htmlentities($_REQUEST["clave"])."'",$link);
$Nclave = mysql_num_rows($clave);
//Si el usuario y clave ingresado son correctos (y el usuario está activo en la BD), creamos la sesión del mismo.
if($Nclave != 0){
session_start();
//Guardamos dos variables de sesión que nos auxiliará para saber si se está o no "logueado" un usuario
$_SESSION["autentica"] = "SI";
$_SESSION["usuarioactual"] = $usuario; //nombre del usuario logueado.
//Direccionamos a nuestra página principal del sistema.
$us=$_REQUEST["email"];
header ("Location: referidos_index.php?us=$xid[0]");
}
else{
echo"<script>alert('La contrase\u00f1a del usuario no es correcta.')
window.location.href=\"referidos_login.php?\"</script>";
}
}else{
echo"<script>alert('El usuario no existe.');window.location.href=\"referidos_login.php\"    </script>";

}
mysql_close($link);

?>
```

and this is the code that i put in every other page to check the session

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["usuarioactual"]))
{
header("Location:referidos_login.php");
die();
}
```

if someone can point me out where the problem is ill be most greatful!!
Thanks.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: You also have to start the session in every other file, before checking the $_SESSION-array!

Comment: and your codes are subjected to SQL Injection. Clean up your input first !

Comment: i started learning php last saturday, for now i just want to know how to do this kind of things and after that think about security, however its true the code is a little messy

Comment: @BorjaGüilesQuintana: If you've just started learning, there's no point in learning the `mysql_*` extension: it's been _deprecated_, and will be removed some time in the future. _learn `PDO` or `mysqli_*`_

Comment: the problem is all the tutorials i find are with  mysql_* so its hard to use other command

Comment: This is totally wrong, in all aspects. I think you should get a professional login/user script and build your app on top of that. Try github.com/panique/php-login if you like...

Comment: the point is learning to make my own, not working on other peoples work.

Comment: @BorjaGüilesQuintana: [Read the red box, and click on the links inside it](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect). There are plenty of examples using `PDO` or `mysqli_*` out there. Also: making your own instead of working on someone else's code might seem like a good idea, but you'll learn a lot more by looking into existing code, and trying to understand _why_ the code is written the way it is, and _how_ it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot, and should not be done without a bit of consideration of security.  If you are learning PHP, please do it the right way.  Please use prepared statements to deal with any user inputted code.  It's a few more lines of code but:

```
$sql="******";
$stmnt=$mysqlidb->prepare($sql);
$stmnt->bind_param("******",******);
$stmnt->execute();
$stmnt->bind_result(******);
while($stmnt->fetch())
    {


    }
$stmnt->close();
```

will allow you to access your password safely - you will need to put your own stuff in place of *****.

if you only need to fetch a single row, the while can be omitted.

Second, store user passwords as hashes -

```
define ("CRYPT_SALT","Random Stuff");
password=SHA1($_POST['password'].CRYPT_SALT);
```

You can't retrieve them but then, no-one else can either.  Compare the hash of the password submitted with the hashed value in the database.

When authenticated, don't pass user data via GET.  Store the user data in $_SESSION instead.
For additional security, create a nonce (a SHA1 hash of microtime() will do) store this in the db and in $_SESSION.

Every time a page is loaded, compare the nonce in $_SESSION with the one in the db against that user's name if they match, you proceed.  Ideally you regenerate a new nonce and update the SESSION and db records so that the  user can see the next page.

This method is about as secure as it gets without storing all the data in a db.  It is up to most applications, especially if you use SSL, and is no harder to code than the lesser system you have suggested.

Comment: thank you for the answer @RobertSeddon-Smith however in the end what i did was use sessions to send data from one page to another, which i believe is also safer. I'll start learning a little about security too, the problem is that if things dont work i get stressed and need a fast answer xD

Comment: Cool.  Just remember that fast answers can leave security holes.  Two years down the line, when you are great at PHP, will you remember the quick fix you made today?  Perhaps it is now part of a different site altogether, just sitting there, waiting to be a nuisance. One security breach can seriously damage the credibility of any site.  Have fun though!